# Is it wrong to prompt for an update on offer letter when I have a deadline with another offer pending?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, hiring-process

I have two offers, one from Company A for a high salary, and one from Company B, for a lower salary.

Company A made me an offer the other week and would like to hear back by today, EOD.

Company B recently made me an offer, and it was lower than I had hoped. I asked if there was anything we could do to get it more in-line with my existing offer. I'm more interested in working with Company B.

They informed me they'd see what they could do, and would get back to me by the end of day. They are also aware that I have an offer pending, due Today, and have been somewhat dragging out the process.

Would it be uncouth to politely prompt Company B for an answer now (mid-day) so I do not miss the cutoff point for Company A?

I would hate to have Company A's offer revoked for taking too long, and then have Company B come back with an offer I don't like. Conversely, I worry it reflects poorly on myself (impatient / greedy / insecure) if I were to prompt Company B mid-day when they said they'd get back to me at the end-of-day.

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely it is not uncouth to prompt Company B to find out where they are.  I would tell them what you wrote here: You are more interested in working with them, but you have another offer on the table and that offer has a deadline, so if they want to hire you then they have to let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

> Would it be uncouth to politely prompt Company B for an answer now
>   (mid-day) so I do not miss the cutoff point for Company A?

No, it's not uncouth at all.

You are simply asking if they can speed things up and mentioning that you have another offer for which you need to respond soon.

It's honest, simple, and has the benefit of telling them that if they don't act quickly you'll take a better offer.

It may or may not work, but it's certainly your best bet.

Make sure your mind is clear on exactly what the minimum would be for you to accept so that you'll be ready. And make sure you are clear in your own mind what you will do if Company B is not able to speed things up. A same-day deadline is often hard to meet.

Comment: And if they don't get back to you, tough. I interviewed at a place that during the interview I told them I had a pending offer and was told that they'd make a decision by that afternoon. Despite having the manager's cell phone number, I never did hear back (I called 3 times and got voice mail every time). They never paid for my 300 mile drive, either.

Answer (score 1):

I think they will get back to you as soon as possible, but obviously have a hard deadline in mind before you go contact company A, if company B is unresponsive.